# How do I run QuestDB from IntelliJ?

Tags: database, questdb

I would like to be able to run QuestDB from IntelliJ so that it sees the data I keep in a particular folder. What class should I run?, how do I set the root folder for the data?, is there anything I need to do regarding configuration (ports and the like)?, do I need to set any size for the memory settings?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have already imported QuestDB as a Maven project in IntelliJ.

In order to start it from the IDE, the entry point is the `io.questdb.ServerMain` class.

Then you need to create a new Run Configuration:

Open the Run/Debug configurations dialog, create a new `Application` configuration and make sure that you point out root dir with a `-d` flag (in the `Program arguments` field). Here's how my configuration looks like:

[image]